# How does spring batch read in chunks? Does it maintain a cursor?

Tags: java, database, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-batch

I want to understand the underlying mechanism of reading data in chunks. I actually want to replicate that code manually.
The database from which we read doesn't support SQL queries which have a way to limit the no of records read. So I am trying to see if I can somehow limit the read to a specific size (just like how spring batch limits one read to a specific chunk size).

Thank you!

Comment: Cursor based reader is usually used. Chunks are batch level construct (not database). There is nothing preventing you from writing your own ItemReader implementation. Chunks come into play after Spring Batch reads configured number of items.

Comment: @PavelHoral Thank you for the response. I am just trying to see the logic behind the scenes for spring batch chunk reading mechanism so I can implement it in my own app which is not a spring batch app.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Batch calls the reader until the configured chunk size is reached or when the datasource is exhausted (ie the reader returns `null`). More specifically, it is the `ChunkProvider` that calls the reader to provide a chunk of items and hand it to the `ChunkProcessor`. You can find the relevant part of the code in the [ChunkOrientedTasklet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/step/item/ChunkOrientedTasklet.java#L67-L76) class.

Chunk processing is explained with a pseudo-code sample in the [chunkOrientedProcessing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/reference/html/step.html#chunkOrientedProcessing) section.

Comment: Thank you! Say the reader query is select * from XYZ. Does the jdbccursoritemreader know to LIMIT/ROWNUM or apply whatever limit to the query and stop at the 1000th record? I want to see that logic behind the scenes, so I can implement it in my own non-batch app.

Comment: The `JdbcCusrorItemReader` opens a cursor on the table and does not limit rows unless `maxRows` parameter is set. `I want to see that logic behind the scenes`: I suggest you take a look at the code of the class: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JdbcCursorItemReader.java

Comment: @Julia I have a feeling that you are missing one point - *cursors* are database constructs, not Spring Batch nor JDBC specific. So pick your favourite database reference documentation and check how *cursors work* (e.g. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-cursors.html).